# Is it possible to store SharePoint users in a MySql database?

Tags: mysql, email, sharepoint-2010, user-accounts, sharepoint-workflow

I have a customer with a very small SharePoint 2010 system where they don't need to log in and they don't have an Active Directory. I think it's always the same person logged in.

They want a workflow where they can choose a person from a list and a notification email will be sent to the person. And they want the data to be stored in a MySql database.

Is it possible to store SharePoint users in a MySql database?

Or can I build a simple MySql table with names and email addresses and then send emails to those from inside a SharePoint workflow? Will SharePoint understand that those are email addresses?

Comment: Why not store the names in a SharePoint list?

Comment: Because the SharePoint environment is not backed up. And the responsible person is most comfortable with MySql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup your web application to use claims authentication and then implement a custom membership provider. There is some implementations for mysql membership providers out there:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12301/Membership-and-Role-providers-for-MySQL

Here is an article about how to setup claims authentication with an ASP.NET membership provider:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252020(v=office.14).aspx

Obviously you need to adapt the implementation to the MySQL Membership provider which should be easy enough.

Sorry about providing links but the ammount of steps is so big that is not suitable to be posted here.

Comment: Here is a good one too: http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2011/01/05/writing-a-custom-membership-provider-and-using-it-for-fba-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-from-the-scratch/

Comment: Thats a good one too. One thing you probably know by now (or allways did) is you can actually implement your own membership providers so you can actually get rid of all the gunk of a generic provider and roll your own with the specs you want need